# Returning Minimum ID in Management Studio

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, ssms

Assume the following:

```
CREATE TABLE #Testing
(
      [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
      [store_id] [varchar](3) NULL,
      [sku] [varchar](14) NULL,
      [qty] [bigint] NULL,
      [http_action] [varchar](20) NULL
)

INSERT INTO #Testing (store_id, sku, qty, http_action)
SELECT '001','123456',1,'POST'
UNION ALL
SELECT '002','123456',1,'POST'
UNION ALL
SELECT '002','123456',1,'DELETE'
UNION ALL
SELECT '001','223456',5,'DELETE'
```

What’s a single query that you could run to return the minimum [id] for each [http_action]?  Something like:

```
MIN_DELETE  MIN_POST
3           1

GO
```

Comment: Where does the three come from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an aggregate function with a `CASE` expression to get the `min(id)` for each `http_action`:

```
select 
  min(case when http_action='DELETE' then id end) Min_Delete,
  min(case when http_action='POST' then id end) Min_Post
from #testing;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/13024).

The above query places the `min(id)` values into separate columns, if you want them in rows, then you could use:

```
select min(id) id,
  http_action
from #testing
group by http_action;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/13025)

Answer (score 0):

Another way of solving it is to use a simple group by on the http_action. You will get a row for each action though:

```
select http_action, MIN(id) min_id from #Testing group by http_action
```

Output:

```
http_action  min_id
DELETE         3
POST           1
```